# Aws SES Sent mail and got email id but not received

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

```
  Ref:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/dotnetv3/SES
```

In SES, Using AWS SDK sent mail in .NET

```
       var bodyHtml =  "This is some HTML body text.  and other HTML elements.";
      var bodyText =  "This is some plain body text.";
      var subject = "Sample email from Amazon Simple Email Service";

     var messageId = await sesWrapper.SendEmailAsync(toAddresses, ccAddresses,
   bccAddresses, bodyHtml, bodyText,
   subject, senderAddress);
```

**Mail Send Successfully and got message id which print last**

[image]

**Error get following**

[image]

Question:

Any steps missing in aws login for SES

Answer (score 0):

There are a few setup steps for SES, did you follow the steps [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/setting-up.html) in the SES developer guide to add a sending account (even if in the sandbox) and enable programmatic access?